# How can I get all records from the table if I don't pass any dates to between clause?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a query
SELECT * FROM table sid
WHERE cast(sid.created_at as date) between  '2020-07-21' and  '2021-07-21'.
This works fine and gives the records between above dates. But I want all the records, if I don't pass the date. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can concatenate the where clause based on the condition of date, if it is present then concate it with base query, if no date is present then just use the base query. By base query I meant, `SELECT * FROM table sid`

Comment: The way to get all the records would be to remove the WHERE clause, so just `SELECT * FROM table`. Is that what you're asking? If not, can you expand a bit on what "if I don't pass the date" means?

Comment: How do you pass the dates?

Comment: **pseodo code(in python)**

`base_query = "SELECT * FROM table sid" 

final_query = base_query if not date else base_query + f"WHERE 

cast(sid.created_at as date) between '2020-07-21' and '2021-07-21'"

// do further process with final_query`

Comment: @WanderNauta means if the dates is passed as an empty string

Comment: @forpas passing the date as string(from :'2020-07-21', to: '2021-07-21') if filter applied, if not then empty string (from : '', to : '')

Comment: Why do you cast created_at to date? What is its data type?

Comment: @forpas created_at is of date type, but passed dates to between clause is of type String. Hence, to compare both dates I have used cast.

Comment: Then there is no need to cast created_at as date. It is a date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one query for both cases:

```
query = """
SELECT * 
FROM sid 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), created_at) AND COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), created_at)
"""
```

If the data type of `created_at` is `DATE` there is no need to cast it to `DATE` again.

If it is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` then:

```
query = """
SELECT * 
FROM sid 
WHERE DATE(created_at) BETWEEN COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), DATE(created_at)) AND COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), DATE(created_at))
"""
```

Then pass the parameters as a tuple:

```
cursor.execute(query, ('2020-07-21', '2021-07-25'))
```

or pass empty strings:

```
cursor.execute(query, ('', ''))
```